# Why am I not able to change UIButton text-color?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift3

I am trying to change the text-color of an `UIButton` programmatically on Swift 3.

I have done it in other buttons but there is only one in the whole project that I cannot change the color and I cannot find why (I can change it manually from storyboard but I need to change its color programmatically). To change the text-color in other buttons I have done the following:

```
customButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

and it works well. Except one `UIButton` that I have inside an `UITableViewCell` in which I cannot change the  text-color to that `UIButton` programmatically. I can change it manually (using storyboard), although.

This is the code that I have for the custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var customButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    customButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    customButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
}
```

but it only changes the background color to yellow.

This is my storyboard configuration (that I do not know if it can be relevant for this purpose):

[image]

I know that the connection to that `UIButton` is working well because the background-color is changing but then,

Why am I not able to change its text-color? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Issue

Setting `tintColor` works only for `buttonType = .custom`. When you create a button using `UIButton()` the default `buttonType` would be `.system` which will override your global `titleLabel` and `tintColor` due to configuration with specific [states](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolstate)

## Solution

If you want the behavior of the system `UIButton` of fading the `titleLabel` when pressing the button, you need to set the `titleColor` for each state like below:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
```

Otherwise you can use `.custom` and set `tintColor` directly.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: Now it works but I cannot understand why. In the rest of buttons of my project I can change it directly using `customButton.tintColor = UIColor.red`. Why is it different here? Or is it something related with the _states of a button_ that I do not really understand what do you mean?

Comment: Thank you! Finally the storyboard was the clue of the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the TintColor as the title Color, the type should be `System` instead of `Custom`

Comment: Thank you! I knew that it should be some ridiculous thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can change its title directly like:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.titleLabel?.textColor = .red
```

Comment: It also does not work. I have the UIButton created manually. I only need to change its text-color property programatically.